# Fourier transform of $ 1/|x|^{k}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

is ist possible to find the Fourier transform (direct and inverse ) of

$ f(x)= \frac{1}{|x|^{k}} $ for $ k=1,2,3,......$

this function has a severe singularity at  $x=0$ so i think this will exists only in the sense of distributions :)

Comment: It's also in the table of distributions in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions).